# TextInput to accept numbers, along with commas and decimal values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I wish to implement a TextInput such that it accepts the amount of money in different possible formats.

For example:

> 250

> 2,50,000

> 2.50

Let's say I type in 2f50, it should be 250. If we type 2.5, it should remain 2.5 and for 2,50,000; it's 2,50,000 only.

My TextInput should accept only numbers, commas, and decimals only.

Comment: Do you care about the validity of the input? Is gibberish like `01.2..33,4` allowed?

Comment: what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Maybe you should format the output instead of the input and if so you could use some regex

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ah = '.45f,,6f7..'
var i = ah.length - 1;

while (i != 0) { 
 if (
   (isNaN(ah[i])  && ah[i] != "." && ah[i] != ",") ||
   ((ah[i] == "," || ah[i] == ".") && (ah[i - 1] == "," || ah[i - 1] == "."))
 ) {
   ah = ah.slice(0, i) + ah.slice(i + 1);
  }
 i--;
 }

if (ah.includes(".") && ah.includes(",")) ah = ah.replace(/,/g, ".");
```

**When the user finishes typing** ie when you want to use your `input` value

1. you check if the `input` value endswith `.` or `,` so you remove it

```js
if (ah.endsWith(".") || ah.endsWith(","))
      ah = ah.slice(0, ah.length - 1) + ah.slice(ah.length);
```

2. you check if the `input` value startswith `.` or `,` so you remove it ( I dont know if you want do this but this is how )

```js
if (ah.startsWith(".") || ah.startsWith(","))
       ah = ah.slice(1, ah.length)
```

**Note :** these tests should not be part of the input control inside the `textfield`, otherwise the user will never be able to type  `.` or `,`